# changing twilio call-state created by twilio.js library hangs up dialed user

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, twilio

I'm using twilio.js to call people through my website.

```
Twilio.Device.connect({
  agent: "Smith",
  phone_number: "4158675309"
});
```

I'm trying to change the state of a connected call. For example:

```
@client = Twilio::REST::Client.new account_sid, auth_token
@call = @client.account.calls.get("CAe1644a7eed5088b159577c5802d8be38")
@call.update(:url => "http://demo.twilio.com/docs/voice.xml",
         :method => "POST")
```

The code above is from my rails app but it's made from an ajax call in javascript.

The problem - when I change the state of the call, the person I dialed gets hung up on. **How I can prevent the dialed user from getting hung up on?**

Comment: What do you want to happen to the call, you are trying to redirect one part of the call, but where should the other part of the call go?

Comment: @philnash I want the dialed user to get redirected and listen to the message. Right now it redirects the call initiator and hangs up on dialed user. I'm trying to create a feature where I dial a number with twilio.js, if I get their voicemail I click a button to start playing my pre-recorded message to leave on their voicemail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

If you want the other leg of the call to be redirected then you need to find the Call Sid of the second leg. I guess you are passing the Call Sid from the Twilio Client call to your server via ajax right now. Since this is the originating call, that will be the parent call sid.

You can then use the REST API to [list calls](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/rest/call#list) with that [call as the parent](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/rest/call#list-get-filters). Here's some Ruby that shows that:

```
@client = Twilio::REST::Client.new account_sid, auth_token
parent_call_sid = params["call_sid"]
child_calls = @client.calls.list(parent_call_sid: parent_call_sid)
child_call = child_calls.first
@call = @client.calls.get(child_call.sid)
@call.update(:url => "http://demo.twilio.com/docs/voice.xml",
         :method => "POST")
```

In this example, I assume there is only one child call and pick the first, but that should probably work in this situation. Notably, redirecting the child call away will hang up on the caller. If you don't want this to happen, include an [`action` attribute on the `<Dial>`](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/twiml/dial#attributes-action) TwiML that you used or add TwiML to follow the [`<Dial>`](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/twiml/dial).

Let me know if that helps at all.

Comment: Thank you very much. I didn't know twilio had separate callsids for each person on the call. I'll try this out and let you know how it goes.

Comment: this is exactly what I want to do. Thanks for the help. You were way more helpful than the twilio support guys. Keep up the great work.

Comment: if you get a chance I have another related question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43218074/update-and-record-ongoing-call